# Java Модификатор доступа protected

Tags: java, классы, protected

В java новичек. Не понимаю как работает модификатор доступа protected. На каждом заборе написано "***protected:* такой класс или член класса доступен из любого места в текущем классе или пакете или в производных классах, даже если они находятся в других пакетах**".
В данном примере класс Prot находится в одном Package с Main. То есть Main должен иметь доступ к Prot. Но это не работает. Выскакивает ошибка "**modifier protected not allowed here**"

```
Package Test.com
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Prot ppp = new Prot();
        System.out.println("Вы ввели: " + ppp.prt());
    }
}
 protected class Prot{
    String prt(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String vvod = scan.nextLine();
        return vvod;
    }
}
```

Comment: А Вы случайно не пробуете прописать класс в том-же, что и Main? В принципе они должны находиться в разных файлах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only public,private and final** allowed for class. Protected только для,  конструкторов, методов и  членов.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй, я так же начинающий джавист. Как я понял модификатором protected помечаются только методы и переменные класса, а не сам класс. Эти методы и переменные видны всем классам в пределах пакета.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем protected поля и методы видны только внутри самого класса (включая inherited классы) и в наследниках.

для package only видимости просто не ставьте модификатор  видимости.